# Python write data via serial port to Vellemank8090

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

everybody,

I'm trying to control the relays from a relay board via Python and write the following code. Unfortunately I always get an error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? For the construction I linked the documentation (see second link). I also found another post where someone is trying to read data from the relay board (see first link). But the code doesn't work for me either.

best regards
till

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

**Useful Info**

[Another post from stackoverflow about read data from Velleman K8090](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862862/python-read-data-via-serial-port-from-velleman-k8090)

[Documentation for USB Relay Board (K8090)](https://www.labviewforum.de/attachment.php?aid=51134)
Here is the documentation for the USB Relay Board ( Velleman K8090).

**My Code**

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.port = 'COM4'
ser.data_bits = 8
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.stop_bits = 1
ser.flow_control = 'N'

ser.open()
print(ser.is_open)

print(str(bytearray([0x04, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, (((~(0x04 + 0x11 + 0x01 + 0x00 + 0x00)) + 0x01) & 0xff), 0x0f])))
data = str(bytearray([0x04, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, (((~(0x04 + 0x11 + 0x01 + 0x00 + 0x00)) + 0x01) & 0xff), 0x0f]))
ser.write(data)

ser.close()
print(ser.is_open)
```

**Output:**

True
bytearray(b'\x04\x11\x01\x00\x00\xea\x0f')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\twinters\Desktop\K8090_V2.py", line 16, in 
    ser.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\twinters\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 308, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Users\twinters\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 63, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: "bytearray(b'\x04\x11\x01\x00\x00\xea\x0f')"

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 `str` creates a unicode string (this is different to python 2.7). You probably want `bytes` instead. Like this:

```
data = bytes(bytearray([0x04, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, (((~(0x04 + 0x11 + 0x01 + 0x00 + 0x00)) + 0x01) & 0xff), 0x0f]))
```